# Get rid of small integer caching under python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm relying on id(obj) to distinguish two objects in my project. However, this doesn't work when objects are small integers unfortunately due to python's small value caching. The following two elements will have the same id.

```
self.a = 0
self.b = 0
# id(self.a) is the same as id(self.b)
```

Is there a way to make id(self.a) different from id(self.b) but still retain the syntax listed above?

Thanks!

EDIT:
See the following example

```
class B:
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = 0

  def eat( self ):
    self.b = 0

class A:
  def __init__(self):
    self.b = B()
    self.a = 0

  def eat1( self ):
    self.a = 0

  def eat2( self ):
    self.b.b = 0

a = A()
a.b.eat()
a.eat2()
```

Basically a.b.eat() is accessing the same variable as a.eat2() and eat1() is accessing a different variable. However, self.b.b and self.a have the same id which makes it hard to distinguish between them.

Comment: Maybe you should explain why you need this behaviour? There is probably a better way of doing it.

Comment: Maybe wrap the integer with a class or make a subclass of int.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there's no runtime way to disable the small integer cache; it is a compile-time option.  You'd need to modify the bytecode compiler anyway, to prevent merging of identical literals in the constants array.

Comment: I want to check if two functions in two classes are accessing the same object. I will add an example above.

Comment: "I'm relying on id(obj) to distinguish two objects in my project. However, this doesn't work when objects are small integers" - *don't rely on equal ints being different objects*. There are many other ways things will break besides the small integer cache if you rely on equal ints not being the same object. For example, every evaluation of the same integer literal (not merely identical literals - actually the same piece of code) in a program will produce the same integer object.

Comment: I'm still not sure why you need to know if two integers are the same object. I'm having trouble imagining a scenario in which that's important.

Comment: "Basically a.b.eat() is accessing the same variable as a.eat2() and eat1() is accessing a different variable. However, self.b.b and self.a have the same id which makes it hard to distinguish between them." Not the variables have the same id but the values bound to those variables. You should show the code that needs to "distinguish" those variables.

Comment: I'm parsing the source of eat, eat1, and eat2 that I got from inspect. Then I see names in the form of string, "self.a", "self.b", and "self.b.b". Then I check the instance dictionary to find out what exactly is "self.b.b" by for example id( getattr( getattr(a, "b"), "b" ) ). Since small integers are cached, id(xxx) are the same if their values are the same.